# How to Display and load images from URL that are visible in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401924/load-image-fastly-from-url), but I didn't get my solution.

I want to display and load images from URL that are visible in `UITableViewCell` and other cell images have to load when we scroll table view in Objective-C.

Comment: Have you used any library, show what you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Async image loading from url inside a UITableView cell - image changes to wrong image while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663618/async-image-loading-from-url-inside-a-uitableview-cell-image-changes-to-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for this. it has almost all features what you need. It's also easy to coding like this.

**Objective C**

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your domain"]
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

**Additional:**

**swift 3:**

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "your domain"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was implementing it but i want to modify it to display/download only visible cells image ..But using this it can download all the cells continuosly ..Can u guide me how to do it

Comment: Welcome.If this answer is helpful i hope you will accept it.:) We are here to help you.:)

Answer (score 0):

Rajashekar simply you can do this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *strCell=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strCell];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:strCell];
    }
    NSString *strImgURL = @"YourImageURL";
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strImgURL];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Data has loaded successfully.");
    }
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    cell.imageView.image = img;

    return cell;
}
```